# `Shift + ESC` in key binding

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to bind `#'window-toggle-side-windows` to the key combination shift and escape. That is hammered into my muscle memory by decades of using Intellij.

The obvious `(global-set-key "s-ESC" #'window-toggle-side-windows)` does not work as expected. It fails recognize the key combination of shift escape.

I am mainly interested in having this work in GUI emacs.

Edit:
`(global-set-key "S-<escape>" #'window-toggle-side-windows)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3):

When defining keybindings in Emacs, it is generally easiest to lookup their 'string representations' pressing `C-h k` followed by pressing the key chords you would like to bind.<sup>1</sup> You will see the 'string representation' in the beginning of the help window. Subsequently, you can simply [wrap it with `kbd`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html) and use it in `define-key` or `global-set-key` etc. as follows:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "S-<escape>") #'window-toggle-side-windows)
```

For some reason, even when knowing about this, this information is still not straightforward to find on the web or within the Emacs documentation. Therefore, I am repeating this answer here.

From Emacs version >= 29, one can use `keymap-set` in which wrapping the string representation with `kbd` is not required anymore.

<sub>1.</sub> <sub>As `ESC` is a prefix key by default, using `C-h k` does not work directly here. In that case you could try pressing `M-: (read-key "Press key (chord): ")` followed by the key (chord), to obtain the string representation.</sub>

Comment: Don't you need to get rid of the `S-<escape> --> ESC` translation somehow? If I do `C-h k S-ESC`, I get `S-<escape>` flashing by in the echo area and quickly replaced by `ESC-` which is a prefix key waiting for me to type something.

Comment: Interesting. I did not notice, as I just started setting the keybinding (after `emacs -q`). Then I quickly checked what `S-ESC` returns, and of course already it was not a prefix key anymore. Anyway, the (main) instruction for setting the keybinding should work correctly, but the instruction about using `C-h k` needs some extra info, however, I'm not about what would be the best advice here.

Comment: Ah, if it doesn't cause trouble in the rebinding, then I think you should just point out the translation possibility (basically just to prevent any confusion like mine) and state that the rebinding works regardless. I was a bit worried that `ESC` might not be a prefix key any longer: I should have tried it out.

Comment: Tested it and it works fine (but you mean `M-: (read-key ...)` - right?)